# How do I call functions from asmx files

Tags: vb.net, web-services, function, asmx

I want to write a function in a Web Service and call it from windows forms.

When I write in it the **"Service.vb"** file in the Web Service, I am able to refer to it from the windows forms.

But I need to write the same function in the **asmx file** and it's not working.

How do I call it when it's in asmx file? Is it different than when it's in the Service.vb file?

Comment: You asked a similar question on a we service returning dataset an hour ago and it is answered.

Comment: @farhanMukadam It worked from a Service.vb file. Didnt work on asmx. Exactly why I'm asking this question :)